# get spring boot's application endpoints absolute full path

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, servlets

sometimes need to test a spring boot application (not produced by me) fast, but cannot easily call endpoints due to intricated properties and some spaghetti code which change the path somewhere.

Are there any methods to expose `full absolute` endpoinds paths on start?
like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43543204/10894456 but I need the full absolute path with port

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a Spring Boot application, you can obtain the full absolute paths of the exposed endpoints along with the port by inspecting the application's `ServletContext`. You can create a custom Spring Bean that exposes this information. Here's an example of how you can achieve this:

1. Create a custom bean to expose endpoint information:

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Component
public class EndpointInfoProvider {
    private final ServletContext servletContext;

    @Autowired
    public EndpointInfoProvider(ServletWebServerApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.servletContext = applicationContext.getServletContext();
    }

    public Map<String, String> getEndpointInfo() {
        Map<String, String> endpointInfo = new HashMap<>();
        
        // Get the server port
        int serverPort = servletContext.getRealServerPort();
        
        // Get the context path (e.g., /your-app-context)
        String contextPath = servletContext.getContextPath();
        
        // Iterate through all the registered servlets and their mappings
        servletContext.getServletRegistrations().forEach((name, registration) -> {
            registration.getMappings().forEach(mapping -> {
                String servletPath = mapping.replaceAll("\\*", "");
                String fullPath = "http://localhost:" + serverPort + contextPath + servletPath;
                endpointInfo.put(name, fullPath);
            });
        });
        
        return endpointInfo;
    }
}
```

2. Now you can inject this bean into your controller or service to access the endpoint information:

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.Map;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class MyController {
    private final EndpointInfoProvider endpointInfoProvider;

    @Autowired
    public MyController(EndpointInfoProvider endpointInfoProvider) {
        this.endpointInfoProvider = endpointInfoProvider;
    }

    @GetMapping("/endpoints")
    public Map<String, String> getEndpoints() {
        return endpointInfoProvider.getEndpointInfo();
    }
}
```

In this example, the `/api/endpoints` endpoint will return a map of servlet names (usually the bean names) and their corresponding full absolute URLs, including the port.

Make sure you have proper error handling and security in place if you decide to expose this information, as it could potentially pose a security risk if not properly protected in a production environment.