# Find all routes on a public API

Tags: python

I found a public API with no doc.
My objective is to be able to find all routes available.

Is there a way to find all routes available ?

For now all i did is navigate on the website and watch network call.
I also search on forums for people trying to have the same approach as mine.

Comment: In general no, there is not.  Technically you could try to guess literally every possibility and see what sticks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of, relevant, or helpful [Is there a way to discover all endpoints of a REST API?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28993965/1248974)

Comment: An API is often confused with a service, but actually it is the *definition* of a service e.g. the documentation.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.